# Datagrid in JSP

Tags: jsp, datagrid

I need to create a Datagrid with a radiobutton column in **JSP**. The grid is to be binded dynamically to a result set and be populated accordingly. This result set is obtained as a result of search in the database. Please do help with a sample source code, or a useful link for the same.

Thanks in advance,
Geetha

Answer (score 1):

[DisplayTag](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/) is a popular taglib for those purposes in "plain vanilla JSP".

---

Alternatively, you can look for a component based MVC framework which usually ships with datagrid components. For example JSF with the standard `h:dataTable` or a JSF component library with a more enriched table, such as RichFaces with [`rich:dataTable`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf), IceFaces with [`ice:dataTable`](http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface) and PrimeFaces with [`p:dataTable`](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/prime-showcase/ui/datatableRowSelection.jsf)